# Is there any way to create a default account whenever a node is created?

Tags: corda

I am using Corda version 4.3 and doing all the transactions on the account level by creating accounts for each node. However, I want that whenever I create a node a default account gets created so that no node is created without an account.

I wonder if I can do that in the RPC settings or in the main build.gradle file where I initialize a node like this :

```
                node {
                      name "O=Node1,L=London,C=GB"
                      p2pPort 10005
                      rpcSettings {
                      address("localhost:XXXXX")
                      adminAddress("localhost:XXXXX")
                                   }
                         rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
                     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Create a class and annotate it as `@CordaService` -which means this class gets loaded as soon as the node starts- (https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.node.services/-corda-service/index.html).
2. Inside your service class:

   - Fetch the default account (`AccountService` class from the Accounts library has methods to fetch and create accounts; it's inside `com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.workflows.services`).
   - If the default account is not found, create it.

Comment: Kudos Adel. I made a service and it served my purpose.

Comment: Great! Can you mark the question as answered please?